# get cell count value from DataGridView in another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to get the cell count values from the DataGridView in another Form, I have Form1 and Form2, in Form2 there is a DataGridView (dgResult) that receives 15 random numbers that come from the DB between 01 to 25, where I do a count of repeated numbers between cells, the number of repetitions is received by a label for each number from 01 to 25, this is all in Form2, I would like to show these Labels with the results of the count in Form1, could someone help me?
I have a class that brings the numbers from the Database:

```
 public int concurso { get; set; }
    public int _01 { get; set; }
    public int _02 { get; set; }
    public int _03 { get; set; }
```

---

```
    public int _15 { get; set; }
```

```
//Class AddResult
public static DataTable ObterNumeros()
        {
            DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
            DALConexao conexao = new DALConexao(DadosDaConexao.StringDaConexao);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conexao.ObjetConexao;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from TBLotofacil ORDER BY Concurso DESC", conexao.StringConexao);
            da.Fill(tabela);
            return tabela;
        }
```

create the header of the grid Form2

```
private void AtualizarInformacoesDoGrid()
    {
        //personalizaGrid();
        dgResultadoGeral.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dgResultadoGeral.DataSource = AddResultado.ObterNumeros();
            if (dgResultadoGeral.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                dgResultadoGeral.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Concurso";
                dgResultadoGeral.Columns[0].Width = 97;
                dgResultadoGeral.Columns[1].HeaderText = "01";
                dgResultadoGeral.Columns[1].Width = 50;
```

---

```
                dgResultadoGeral.Columns[15].HeaderText = "15";
                dgResultadoGeral.Columns[15].Width = 50;
```

...
get cell count results Form2

```
  public void calculaTotalGrid()
        {
            int outVal = 0;
            ResultadoNumeros = dgResultadoGeral.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .SelectMany(r => r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                .Where(c => c.ColumnIndex > 0 && int.TryParse(c.Value?.ToString(), out outVal)))
                .GroupBy(c => int.Parse(c.Value.ToString()))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

            int count1 = ResultadoNumeros[01];
            lbl_01.Text = count1.ToString();
//fron 01 to 25 
            int count25 = ResultadoNumeros[25];
            lbl_25.Text = count25.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Hello! From your previous question, you have the class field: `private Dictionary<int, int> ResultadoNumeros;` that you create in the `calculaTotalGrid` method. You can change the modifier to `internal` to access it from the other form. `internal Dictionary<int, int> ResultadoNumeros;`. Is that acceptable? But, make sure to create the dictionary before trying to access it from elsewhere. Also, that class encapsulates `public int _01 { get; set; }` ...etc. You don't need it anymore. You have the dictionary as a replacement.

Comment: face! I'm very noob, I created the method calculaTotalGrid() of form2 in Form1 and created the internal Dictionary<int, int> ResultadoNumeros; in Form1 too but when calling the gridView (dgResultadoSalvos) of form2 in Form1 gives error: dgResultadoSalvos does not exist in the current context

Comment: You don't access the `form2` controls from `form1`. Access the dictionary only. Why do you need the grid in `form1` for?

Comment: the grid is in Form2, I want to get the results of the grid that is in form2 and show it in lbl01, lbl02, in form1 through the load of form1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.

**form2**

The `DataGridView` Form.

```cs
public class form2 : Form
{
    private Dictionary<int, int> _resultadoNumeros;

    public form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
            
        // ...etc.
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        // Load the data and populate the DataGridView then call...
        DisplayTheResults();
    }

    internal Dictionary<int, int> RresultadoNumeros
    {
        get
        {
            if (_resultadoNumeros == null)
            {
                int outVal = 0;
                _resultadoNumeros = dgResultadoGeral.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .SelectMany(r => r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                    .Where(c => c.ColumnIndex > 0 && int.TryParse(c.Value?.ToString(), out outVal)))
                    .GroupBy(c => int.Parse(c.Value.ToString()))
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
            }

            return _resultadoNumeros;
        }
    }

    private void DisplayTheResults()
    {
        lbl_01.Text = RresultadoNumeros[1].ToString();
        lbl_02.Text = RresultadoNumeros[2].ToString();
        lbl_03.Text = RresultadoNumeros[3].ToString();
        //...
        lbl_25.Text = RresultadoNumeros[25].ToString();
    }
}
```

Note, you can benefit from the `Tag` property to map the labels to the dictionary and populate the labels in a loop. In the designer of each Form (`form1` and `form2`), select `lbl_01` and press `F4`, find the `Tag` property in the Properties window and assign `1`. Do the same for the other 25 labels and assign the corresponding values `2`, `3`, ... `25`. The `DisplayTheResults` method now should look like this:

```cs
private void DisplayTheResults()
{
    // assuming the Form is the parent of the labels.
    foreach (var lbl in Controls.OfType<Label>())
    {
        int outKey;

        if (int.TryParse(lbl.Tag?.ToString(), out outKey) &&
            RresultadoNumeros.ContainsKey(outKey))
        {
            lbl.Text = RresultadoNumeros[outKey].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

If the labels are hosted by different containers, then use a recursive method to get them:

```cs
private void DisplayTheResults()
{
    foreach (var lbl in GetChildren(this).OfType<Label>())
    {
        int outKey;

        if (int.TryParse(lbl.Tag?.ToString(), out outKey) &&
            RresultadoNumeros.ContainsKey(outKey))
        {
            lbl.Text = RresultadoNumeros[outKey].ToString();
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<Control> GetChildren(Control parent)
{
    var controls = parent.Controls.Cast<Control>();
    return controls.SelectMany(c => GetChildren(c)).Concat(controls);
}
```

**form1**

```cs
public class form1 : Form
{
    public form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // ...etc.
    }

    private void WhereYouCreateAndShowForm2()
    {
        using (var frm = new form2())
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
            DisplayTheResults(frm.RresultadoNumeros);
        }
    }

    private void DisplayTheResults(Dictionary<int, int> dict)
    {
        foreach (var lbl in Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {
            int outKey;

            if (int.TryParse(lbl.Tag?.ToString(), out outKey) &&
                dict.ContainsKey(outKey))
            {
                lbl.Text = dict[outKey].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if you need to show `from1` from `form2`, then pass the dictionary to `form1` through a parameterized constructor.

**form1**

```cs
public class form1 : Form
{
    public form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // ...etc.
    }

    public form1(Dictionary<int, int> dict) : this()
    {
        DisplayTheResults(dict);
    }        

    private void DisplayTheResults(Dictionary<int, int> dict)
    {
        foreach (var lbl in Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {
            int outKey;

            if (int.TryParse(lbl.Tag?.ToString(), out outKey) &&
                dict.ContainsKey(outKey))
            {
                lbl.Text = dict[outKey].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**form2**

```cs
public class form2 : Form
{
    private Dictionary<int, int> _resultadoNumeros;

    public form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
            
        // ...etc.
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        // Load the data and populate the DataGridView then call...
        DisplayTheResults();
    }

    internal Dictionary<int, int> RresultadoNumeros
    {
        get
        {
            if (_resultadoNumeros == null)
            {
                int outVal = 0;
                _resultadoNumeros = dgResultadoGeral.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .SelectMany(r => r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                    .Where(c => c.ColumnIndex > 0 && int.TryParse(c.Value?.ToString(), out outVal)))
                    .GroupBy(c => int.Parse(c.Value.ToString()))
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
            }

            return _resultadoNumeros;
        }
    }

    private void DisplayTheResults()
    {
        foreach (var lbl in Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {
            int outKey;

            if (int.TryParse(lbl.Tag?.ToString(), out outKey) &&
                RresultadoNumeros.ContainsKey(outKey))
            {
                lbl.Text = RresultadoNumeros[outKey].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private void WhereYouCreateAndShowForm1()
    {
        using (var frm = new form1(RresultadoNumeros))
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Form2 loaded up to number 15, from 17 to 25 it was blank, with the calculaTotalGrid() it loaded all, form1 nothing happens, I used code n1 Form2 and n3 Form1, the last two I didn't test because from what you said is to move from Form1 to Form2, I want the reverse, from Form2 (frnResultadoSalvo) to initial Form1 (frmBoaSorte), with the Tag I think it had no effect.

Comment: one thing I noticed, when I put "WhereYouCreateAndShowForm2()" in public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             WhereYouCreateAndShowForm2();
         }
open form2 first and when closing form2 it appears in form1 otherwise it does not appear in form1, so I will study a way to change the project and open the result first, until then I am very grateful for your help, I will be back to give you news, um hug.

Comment: my friend! I apologize for my ignorance, after so much analysis, I realized that the result did not appear in form1 because my numbers were inside a Panel, I removed the panel and everything worked, not automatically as I imagined, but when opening form2 the result comes to form1, I thought if through a progress bar it would not automatically load to form1? I'm going to try here with this code you created, thank you very much for helping me, a big hug.

Comment: I managed to make it appear even with the Panel, I added it to the "foreach (var lbl in panel2.Controls.OfType<Label>())" , now it's time to update form1 without having to open form2, let's try. a hug.

Comment: I'm bothering you again, just a question, I'm creating a page in MDI parent with two buttons, Form1.Click and Form2.click, how would I call the result of form2 for form1? clicking from the initial menu, I wanted to create a new question, but I don't even know how to make a question like that lol, thanks again, you've already given me a great help, a hug

Comment: Oops, I managed to do what I wanted, thank you very much for your help, your help was critical for me to succeed, but I'm already getting hit with another subject kkkkk  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76544649/whenever-the-text-file-changes-a-parameter-in-the-text-create-a-new-text-file-c?noredirect=1#comment134965041_76544649