# Whenever the text file changes a parameter in the text, create a new text file c#

Tags: c#, file, text, readline

I'm creating an application where every day I receive a text via URL and saved as a text file in the project folder, but every day the file is overwritten, I wanted to save a new file every day, Ex: 2845, 2846, 2847 and so on, only create a new one if the number variable is updated, using the "number" variable, I need to do a search and find the text file referring to the number with the details of the raffle, but I'm not getting it, could someone help me? I only get one file per day, I'm using this code to create the text

```
private void Details()
 {
     List<string> lastSorteio = new List<string>();
     string siteLotofacil = @"https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/lotofacil";

     var requisition = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(siteLotofacil);
     requisition.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;
     requisition.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
     request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
     var response = (HttpWebResponse)requisicao.GetResponse();

     using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
     {
         using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(directory + "C:\\BoaSorte\\currentResult.txt"), FileMode.Create))
         {
             responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
         }
     }
 }
```

and I'm reading like this

```
   private void ReadFile()
 {
     var file = new StreamReader("C:\\BoaSorte\\currentresult.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
     stringline;

     while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
         // Initialize array of 5 sequential integers.
         contestlist.Items.Add(line.ToString());

     file.Close();
 }
```

I have a Result class with the variables

```
public Resultado()
    {
        this.idLoteria = idLoteria;
        this.acumulado = acumulado;
        this.dataApuracao = dataApuracao;
        this.dataProximoConcurso = dataProximoConcurso;
        this.dezenasSorteadasOrdemSorteio = dezenasSorteadasOrdemSorteio;
        this.exibirDetalhamentoPorCidade = exibirDetalhamentoPorCidade;
        this.id = id;
        this.indicadorConcursoEspecial = indicadorConcursoEspecial;
        this.listaDezenas = listaDezenas;
        this.listaDezenasSegundoSorteio = listaDezenasSegundoSorteio;
        this.listaMunicipioUFGanhadores = listaMunicipioUFGanhadores;
        this.listaRateioPremio = listaRateioPremio;
        this.listaResultadoEquipeEsportiva = listaResultadoEquipeEsportiva;
        this.localSorteio = localSorteio;
        this.nomeMunicipioUFSorteio = nomeMunicipioUFSorteio;
        this.nomeTimeCoracaoMesSorte = nomeTimeCoracaoMesSorte;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.numeroConcursoAnterior = numeroConcursoAnterior;
        this.numeroConcursoFinal_0_5 = numeroConcursoFinal_0_5;
        this.numeroConcursoProximo = numeroConcursoProximo;
        this.numeroJogo = numeroJogo;
        this.observacao = observacao;
        this.premiacaoContingencia = premiacaoContingencia;
        this.tipoJogo = tipoJogo;
        this.tipoPublicacao = tipoPublicacao;
        this.ultimoConcurso = ultimoConcurso;
        this.valorArrecadado = valorArrecadado;
        this.valorAcumuladoConcurso_0_5 = valorAcumuladoConcurso_0_5;
        this.valorAcumuladoConcursoEspecial = valorAcumuladoConcursoEspecial;
        this.valorAcumuladoProximoConcurso = valorAcumuladoProximoConcurso;
        this.valorEstimadoProximoConcurso = valorEstimadoProximoConcurso;
        this.valorSaldoReservaGarantidora = valorSaldoReservaGarantidora;
        this.valorTotalPremioFaixaUm = valorTotalPremioFaixaUm;

    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move

Comment: You have the filename hardcoded so its always the same.  Add a method to devise a unique name (perhaps using the date???)  to be used each time.  There are several details we cant know such as if there is just one file per day and so forth.

Comment: The use of Path.Combine is also messed up.

Comment: I'd also advise to code in English. That makes it much easier to share it on platforms like here.

Comment: Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp I receive one file per day yes, there will not be more than one per day, how can I get it by the "numero":"xxxx": parameter:? this will always be different every day, if you look at the link above you will see the context of the file.

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on a value that's _already_ a string (like `line`) is a beginner mistake :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a single file per day in a given directory that can be overwritten or appended to, append the [`DateTime.Today`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-today) date to the file name, [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.Path.Combine)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0) the directory and file name to create the path, and [`Path.ChangeExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.changeextension?view=net-7.0) to add the extension.

```cs
private string GetFileName()
{
    var dir = @"c:\BoaSorte";
    var datePart = DateTime.Today.ToString("MMddyyyy");
    var fileName = "Result";
    var file = Path
        .ChangeExtension(Path
        .Combine(dir, $"{fileName}{datePart}"), "txt");

    return file;
}
```

To create a unique file per call with a particular pattern, concatenate the file path in a loop and break it if the file doesn't exist by calling the [`File.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-7.0) method.

```cs
private string GetUniqueFile()
{
    var dir = @"c:\BoaSorte";
    var suffix = DateTime.Today.ToString("MMddyyyy");
    var fileName = "Result";
    int fileNum = 1;
    string outFile;

    while (true)
    {
        outFile = Path.Combine(dir, $"{fileName}{suffix}{fileNum}.txt");
        if (!File.Exists(outFile)) break;
        fileNum++;
    }

    return outFile;
}
```

Better, have a utility method for this function that takes and concatenate the individual parts of the file. For example:

```cs
internal static class Utils
{
    internal static string GetUniqueFile(
        string dir,
        string fileName,
        string suffix,
        int seed,
        string extension)
    {
        string outFile;

        while (true)
        {
            outFile = Path
                .ChangeExtension(Path
                .Combine(dir, $"{fileName}{suffix}{seed}"), extension);
            if (!File.Exists(outFile)) break;
            seed++;
        }

        return outFile;
    }
}
```

Call it from your methods like this:

```cs
private void Details()
{
    var lastSorteio = new List<string>();
    var siteLotofacil = @"https...";
    var file = Utils.GetUniqueFile(
        @"c:\BoaSorte", "currentResult", "-", 2846, "txt");

    // ...

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)requisition.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: hello dr.null, Always grateful for the great help, I reformulated the question for you to understand better, I tried to use it in the Utils class like this int fileNum = Result.numero; to save it like this "currentResult-2846.txt" but it didn't work, if I manage to save it like this I'll be very grateful, I'll correct the search myself, thanks

Comment: @EdilsonLemos Try it now, added `seed` param. If that's what you mean.

Comment: dr.null thank you very much again, it was not 100% as I wanted but it will help me, I wanted to save the text with the "number" variable of the text file but not increase the ++, because every day there is a "number" " new, it's automatic, I only need to create the ninth text if the "number" parameter is updated, a hug.

Comment: @EdilsonLemos Where does `number` come from? If you know that number then it's as simple as: `var file = Path.Combine(@"c:\BoaSorte", $"currentResult-{Result.numero}.txt");`. Assuming `Result` is an instance of `Resultado` class.

Comment: damn! it was in my face! it was perfect, I think I'll put your name as a contributor to the application hehehe, man! you did almost half of the code, thanks a lot, without you I wouldn't have left, if you have a channel, pages, put it there I'll be following you, a big hug